# Synonyms for "put somebody through their paces"?

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms, american-english, speech

What are some verbs and phrases to describe testing someone to see what they are capable of? I already know "put somebody through their paces".

Comment: What wrong with testing them?

Comment: Interview them.

Comment: How harsh a run are we planning? There's a difference between put through their paces and tested by fire.

Comment: I should question whether phrase in the question is of the type to have a synonym.  It is true that standard definitions of 'synonym' speak of equivalence between one 'word or phrase' and another 'word or phrase'.  But the examples of usage are almost entirely of single words and at most couple of words or so.  This is, in effect a single word request, surely.  That said, what is wrong with 'Try somebody out'?  And what is wrong with "putting someone through their paces"?

Comment: Related might be a [shakedown cruise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakedown_cruise)... does that fit?

Comment: Perhaps not what OP's after, but some harsh ones for fun: 1. To have someone run the gauntlet, and 2. To put someone through the wringer. A milder one, but adversarial in that the opportunity to prepare is withheld: 3. To put someone on the spot. Note that 1 and 3 (particularly 3) are well-suited (but not restricted to) unpleasantly public trials.

Answer (score 0):

probation
: critical examination and evaluation or subjection to such examination and evaluation

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/probation

Crucible
: a severe test

.... as in Arthur Miller's play of the same name. i.e
"Putting them into a crucible"

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crucible?topic=testing-checking-and-experimenting

Answer (score 0):

There's **dry run**, which means to test someone or something in a manner that doesn't jeopardize anything already in place, or in a manner that if something does go wrong, the damage can be contained, if not fully prevented. The dress rehearsal of a play can be called a "dry run".

> Let's give it a dry run and see how it does.
>
> I think she'll work out well. Let's send her on a dry run down to Acme Widgets and see what they think. The CEO there is a buddy of mine from college; we could even send *you* down there and still not lose that account.